# How to approximate colors

Tags: flutter, colors, hex

We have a list like this https://htmlcolorcodes.com/color-names/ with come colors named. I want a function that will game some random hex color value and approximate it to one of those named colors. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I understood you correctly you want to a function which:

1. Generates a random color
2. Finds the nearest color in the linked list

Is it correct?
If so, I would recommend to work with the RGB value and then I would create my own metric to measure the distance between two colors like:

```
int distance(Color a, Color b) {
    int redDistance = math.abs( a.red - b.red );
    int greenDistance = math.abs( a.green - b.green );
    int blueDistance = math.abs( a.blue - b.blue );

    return redDistance + greenDistance + blueDistance;
}
```

After that I would iterate over all the linked colors and find the "nearest" color of the random generated.